# Mass background color change of Word files

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I have around 400 Word files and I'm looking for a way to replace the background color for all of them with a script. Is that something that can be achieved in any way?

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far, and what *specific* problem do you need help with?

Comment: Ansgar, I was not expecting someone to give me a full code. I was looking for a way to approach this problem, and to understand if it's even possible to solve.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to record the change(s) you want to make as a VBA macro, translate that macro from VBA to PowerShell, then loop over the documents to modify them.

```psh
$wd = New-Object -COM 'Word.Application'
$wd.Visible = $true   # set to $false for production

Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder\with\*.docx' | % {
  $doc = $wd.Documents.Open($_.FullName)

  # your modifications to $doc here

  $doc.Save()
  $doc.Close()
}

$wd.Quit()
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wd)
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

I wrote a guide for [translating VBA to VBScript](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vba2vbs.shtml) a while ago. Most of it should be applicable to PowerShell as well, although there are some differences:

- Collection items must be accessed as `.Collection.Item(x)`. The abbreviated syntax `.Collection(x)` that works in VBScript doesn't work in PowerShell.
- Parentheses are required for function calls (`.Close()` instead of `.Close`).
- Parameters can't be omitted. You must use `[Type]::Missing` if you want a parameter to have its default value.

Comment: I'm now trying to modify $doc within the function you provided : `$doc.Background.Fill.ForeColor.Blue
$doc.Background.Fill.Solid` but no success.. also,I understand that powershell only support 16 basic ConsoleColor enumeration values?

Comment: @xRoyDot Console colors have nothing to do with this. Please post a new question with the code you currently have. Also, note that `$doc.Background.Fill.ForeColor` does not have a property `Blue`.